# Where do I find a table / listing of all currently airing anime series?

Tags: resources

Is there a website or any kind of document that shows all currently airing series in Japan? Airing dates and times would be great too.

Comment: I think you should definitely narrow down this question to at least a country, but preferably a specific TV network or set of channels. Note StackExchange is an international site. Do you want all series airing everywhere in the world?

Comment: @SF. Considering anime airings outside japan are quire scarce, it is obvious I mean original japanese airing.

Comment: @Euphoric: Not totally obvious, so I think the comment is merited. Note that I [opened up a discussion](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/81/20) on meta about the validity of questions like these, you may want to provide your input too.

Comment: We're not totally sure on the outcome of the above discussion, but there's a tendency towards letting these stay open in the beginning. As such, voted to reopen.

Comment: @Euphoric Unless you include that in the question itself, the question stays broad. Edit it and make it more specific. :)

Comment: [Note that we decided to reopen this question based on this conversation in chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7889679#7889679)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use http://countdown.mandragon.info/ which shows the day and time of the next episode for currently airing shows and dates for shows that will be broadcast soon.

Edit: This site is now down, so I'll recommend another one I use often: http://anichart.net/

Comment: I like this, because it shows nice countdowns.

Comment: This site seems to be down. I don't know if this is temporary or permanent. Luckily there are lots of other alternatives here, most of which still work.

Answer (score 9):

There's [AnimeCalendar](http://animecalendar.net), which, when you make an account and are logged in, lets you filter the series and also convert to your local timezone.

Comment: It also gives you an iCal link which you can export to your personal calander program

Answer (score 8):

There's a MAL Group that updates with the season, has airing dates for all the anime airing during that time and such. [It's right here.](http://myanimelist.net/clubs.php?cid=743)

Comment: I feel honored... :)

Answer (score 4):

I always use [Mahou.org](http://www.mahou.org/Showtime/?o=ET), which not only tells you what is airing, but gives you up-to-the-minute information on precisely when it is airing. However, you'll need to cross-check the listed shows with some other site like [MAL](http://myanimelist.net/), [AniDB](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=main) (note the convenient links to the right of the table), or [ANN's Encyclopedia](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/) if you want descriptions.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the [Fansub Wiki](http://www.fansubwiki.com/Who_Subs_What%3a_WINTER_2012) which separates out each season, includes the time/date/channel, is updated (at least regularly enough these days) to show which shows get picked up by which groups that aren't licensed by U.S. distributors. Crunchyroll, Funimation, and Sentai pick up large handfuls of shows each season these days so the actual fansub groups are less relevant now.

---

EDIT:

I just noticed today that [ANN has an upcoming anime list](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime/upcoming/tv).

Comment: Note that fansubs are not tolerated / promoted on Anime.SE, so I don't think that counts as a valid answer.

Comment: @Xeo Despite the name of the site, it's only content is seasonal lists of what shows air, when, what channel, and which ones have been licensed. Aside from the names of some groups next to ones that aren't licensed, there's no links to any fansubs, where to find them, or how to obtain them. If the mention of "fansubs" at all isn't tolerated then maybe a question should be raised on meta?

Comment: The link is dead, and I think it moved to https://fansubdb.com/

Answer (score 3):

[Neregate](http://neregate.com/blog/anime-charts/) also has charts of all animes, OVAs/movies/whatever else will be airing the next season. (So you can check what was the "next season" of last season, i.e. this season.)

Note that while the charts on Neregate are family-friendly, other elements of the website may contain NSFW content.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has listings of anime per year. For example: [Anime Television Series of 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:2012_anime_television_series).